# Chrome 64 for Android not autoplaying video even when muted

Tags: android, html5-video

Odd one here.

Chrome 64.0.3282.137 for Android is no longer **autoplaying** videos. The video shows but it just sits on the first frame.

Chrome 63 autoplayed them fine. Chrome on desktop is fine and iOS autoplays the video also.

I have the muted, autoplay and playsinline attributes on my video element.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: any updates regarding this issue?